# log4j_init_tomcat.properties not found on SAP Hybris Commerce 2011

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Recently we're trying to upgrade our hybris version, until 2005, everything is fine, but on 2011 I got this error when starting server :

```
ERROR StatusLogger File not found in file system or classpath: log4j_init_tomcat.properties
ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for '2f8e39b4' at 'null' in 'null'
```

That error is not a blocker and the server startup successfully, the problem is, looks like the logger is not initialized/detected, and I notice until server startup there are a lot less logs than the usual. All extension's log is not being logged. If I check on HAC -> Platform -> logging, I only got 2 entries, usually I have up to 22 entries.

I try to search for log4j_init_tomcat.properties on 1811, 1905, and 2005 (using `find . -iname log4j_init_tomcat.properties` and `locate log4j_init_tomcat.properties`) but I can't find that file.

This is Logging configuration in HAC :
[image: Logging configuration in HAC]

Full log when starting server, then stopping server :

```
Running hybrisPlatform on Tomcat...
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Java Service Wrapper Professional Edition 64-bit 3.5.29
  Copyright (C) 1999-2016 Tanuki Software, Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
    http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com
  Licensed to SAP SE for hybris Platform

Launching a JVM...
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
WrapperManager: Initializing...
Jan 18, 2021 4:46:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9001"]
Jan 18, 2021 4:46:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jan 18, 2021 4:46:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-9002"]
Jan 18, 2021 4:46:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jan 18, 2021 4:46:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009"]
Jan 18, 2021 4:46:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jan 18, 2021 4:46:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 652 ms
Jan 18, 2021 4:46:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Jan 18, 2021 4:46:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.57
Jan 18, 2021 4:46:57 PM de.hybris.tomcat.ConfigurableRfc6265CookieProcessor$JuliLogHandler info
INFO: No Same Site cookie config file found at tomcat\bin\sameSiteCookies.properties
Loading additional classes from: [file:/home/hybris/bin/platform/resources/libpatches/spring-web-patch-5.2.9.RELEASE-1.jar]
ERROR StatusLogger File not found in file system or classpath: log4j_init_tomcat.properties
ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for '7a217bbe' at 'null' in 'null'
Jan 18, 2021 4:47:00 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jan 18, 2021 4:47:00 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jan 18, 2021 4:47:00 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jan 18, 2021 4:47:00 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jan 18, 2021 4:47:07 PM de.hybris.platform.solr.controller.commands.StartSolrServersCommand executeCommand
INFO: Starting Solr servers ...
Jan 18, 2021 4:47:07 PM de.hybris.platform.solr.controller.commands.StartSolrServerCommand getSolrServerStatus
INFO: Checking Solr server status for instance [name: default, hostname: localhost, port: 8983, mode: STANDALONE]
Jan 18, 2021 4:47:07 PM de.hybris.platform.solr.controller.commands.StartSolrServerCommand startSolrServer
INFO: Starting Solr server for instance [name: default, hostname: localhost, port: 8983, mode: STANDALONE]
Waiting up to 180 seconds to see Solr running on port 8983 [\]  
Started Solr server on port 8983 (pid=38669). Happy searching!

    
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by ma.glasnost.orika.converter.builtin.CloneableConverter (file:/home/hybris/bin/platform/ext/core/lib/orika-core-1.5.2.jar) to method java.lang.Object.clone()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of ma.glasnost.orika.converter.builtin.CloneableConverter
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'springmvc'
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'springmvc'
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'springmvc'
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'DispatcherServlet'
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'springmvc'
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'springmvc'
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'springmvc-v2'
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'DispatcherServlet'
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'springmvc'
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'springmvc'
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'springmvc'
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'springmvc'
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'DispatcherServlet'
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'springmvc'
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'springmvc'
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:55 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'springmvc'
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'springmvc'
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:58 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'springmvc'
Jan 18, 2021 4:48:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 18, 2021 4:49:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 18, 2021 4:49:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 18, 2021 4:49:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'DispatcherServlet'
Jan 18, 2021 4:49:02 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jan 18, 2021 4:49:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 18, 2021 4:49:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'springmvc'
Jan 18, 2021 4:49:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 18, 2021 4:49:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'DispatcherServlet'
Jan 18, 2021 4:49:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'DispatcherServlet'
Jan 18, 2021 4:49:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 18, 2021 4:49:03 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jan 18, 2021 4:49:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 18, 2021 4:49:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'springmvc'
Jan 18, 2021 4:49:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'DispatcherServlet'
Jan 18, 2021 4:49:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'springmvc'
Jan 18, 2021 4:49:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'DispatcherServlet'
Jan 18, 2021 4:50:09 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9001"]
Jan 18, 2021 4:50:09 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-9002"]
Jan 18, 2021 4:50:09 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009"]
Jan 18, 2021 4:50:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 191925 ms

^CINT trapped.  Shutting down.
shutting down hybris registry..
Sending stop command to Solr running on port 8983 ... waiting up to 180 seconds to allow Jetty process 38669 to stop gracefully.
ERROR StatusLogger File not found in file system or classpath: log4j_init_tomcat.properties
ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for 'Default' at 'null' in 'null'
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Tomcat configuration :

```
java.opts.gc = -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseTLAB -Xlog:gc:${HYBRIS_LOG_DIR}/tomcat/java_gc.log
java.opts.jmx = -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
java.opts.log = -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j_init_tomcat.properties
java.opts.dirs = -Dcatalina.base=%CATALINA_BASE% -Dcatalina.home=%CATALINA_HOME% -Djava.io.tempdir=${HYBRIS_TEMP_DIR}
java.opts.enc = -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
java.opts.oom = -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=${HYBRIS_LOG_DIR}/tomcat

java.time.zone=-Duser.timezone=Asia/Jakarta
tomcat.generaloptions = -server ${java.opts.mem} ${java.opts.gc} ${java.opts.jmx} ${java.opts.log} ${java.opts.dirs} ${java.opts.enc} ${java.opts.oom} -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false ${java.time.zone}
tomcat.javaoptions=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false
```

Where can I find that file, and what is the content of the file?

Thanks and regards,

Adiputera

Comment: Off-topic: How did you make the colors violet? Isn't that supposed to be blue?

Comment: It's appear blue on my device, but when I take screenshots it change slightly to violet, not sure if it's a bug from Ubuntu or just I'm not running correct driver @geffchang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, remove `${java.opts.log}` from `tomcat.generaloptions` and add it to `tomcat.javaoptions`

```
java.opts.gc = -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseTLAB -Xlog:gc:${HYBRIS_LOG_DIR}/tomcat/java_gc.log
java.opts.jmx = -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
java.opts.log = -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j_init_tomcat.properties
java.opts.dirs = -Dcatalina.base=%CATALINA_BASE% -Dcatalina.home=%CATALINA_HOME% -Djava.io.tempdir=${HYBRIS_TEMP_DIR}
java.opts.enc = -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
java.opts.oom = -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=${HYBRIS_LOG_DIR}/tomcat

java.time.zone=-Duser.timezone=Asia/Jakarta
tomcat.generaloptions = -server ${java.opts.mem} ${java.opts.gc} ${java.opts.jmx} ${java.opts.dirs} ${java.opts.enc} ${java.opts.oom} -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false ${java.time.zone}
tomcat.javaoptions=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false ${java.opts.log}
```